# Get running session count from IIS for my hosted Asp.Net web site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, hosting

I am hosting an Asp.Net website in IIS 6.0

We have to reset the session timeout in web.config

My client want me to reset it only if no session is running (no one is using the site).

We have not used Membership and SessionState is set to InProc

How I get to know if anybody using the site or any session is running.

I can't make change in source code or any other file except web.config in the hosted website.

Comment: So he wants to add a new feature, without changing the code?  This isn't really possible, in any case, but you can get a best-guess by tracking activity (not sessions.)  That said, the only other option is as mentioned, look at the log files.  Also, since it is a shared host, maybe they have some features in the site control panel (if they gave you one) that show you the logs/activity?  Perhaps call them and request something like that, or see how they can help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not great at PowerShell, so hopefully you can look up the proper syntax. But ...

One option is to run a Powershell script and check the count of the session like this:

**UPDATE: Changed 'Sessions Total' to 'Sessions Active'**

```
write-host Getting performance counters ...

$perfCounterString = "\asp.net applications(__total__)\sessions active" 
$counter = get-counter -counter $perfCounterString 
$rawValue = $counter.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue 

write-host Session Count is $rawValue

if( $rawValue -gt 0)
{
   write-host Session are active - will not stop IIS
   exit
}

write-host Stopping IIS
stop-service "IISAdmin"

# Set values 
$webConfig = "d:\web.config"
$newTimeout = "20"

# Open file and change value
$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load($webConfig)
$doc.SelectSingleNode("//sessionState").timeout = $newTimeout
$doc.Save($webConfig)

write-host Starting IIS
start-service "IISAdmin"
write-host Done!
```

Save this on the desktop as "ChangeIIS.ps1".

Now Powershell doesn't like you just running scripts like .bat files. You have to grant access to the process or your user for security reasons. So do the following:

1. Open a command prompt and Run As Administrator
2. Type `powershell`
3. Type `Set-ExecutionPolicy -scope process Bypass`
4. Type `sl <path to directory of .sp1 file>` . `sl` [set-location] is like `cd` in command prompt
5. Type `$ '.\ChangeIIS.ps1'`

It will run now and reset the value.

Here is a link to my blog on [how I created the PowerShell script](http://dommyzee.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/using-powershell-to-modify.html)
 in a more Step-by-step fashion

Comment: I don't know anything about PowerShell. can you give example of how to create and execute it, is it safe to run on server?

Comment: Yes it is safe, as you know what the script is doing.

Comment: This looks great, will let you know after testing it.

Comment: I run the partial code , just to check what count it prints. I saw 18. later I search more and chnaged "\asp.net applications(__total__)\sessions total" to "\asp.net applications(__total__)\sessions active" and it shows 2 count, i created another session and the count increased to 3. I checked again and found that no other user is using the site, I think the count be 3 because 2 users might be using some other site hosted in IIS. Can you make the code site specific? is my change fine for checking active session count only or do I need to change something more?

Comment: Yes you are right, use active. Total is a total of abandoned, timeout and active. It can be made site specific. The __Total__ gathers all instances together. To see what other ones are available open "perfmon.exe" and add a performance counter for ASP.NET Applications, Sessions Active and there is a sub category there, as well as __Total__. It should name the active instances

Answer (score 2):

Check the IIS log files for your site and see when the last hit was made (by actual users, rather than search bots).

If the last hit was older than the current session timeout, then no active sessions exist. That is what you are actually looking for, rather than a count.

No programming or hacks required.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I can see the log folder , but when I try to open it it says that I don't have access permission.

Comment: Can you please post the folder path you're trying to open? 

Also, is it the _folder_ or the _log file_ you're trying to open?

If you're hosting the site, you should have an account with _some_ elevated level of permissions?

Comment: On IIS6, logs are defaulted to folder C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles\ and then a subfolder W3SVC _12345678_. Can you use IIS6 manager to check that logging is enabled on the site - that will show you the actual folder path and W3SVC folder name.

Comment: That looks odd as it would suggest that logs can be requested from the browser, and that might be a security weakness. Anyway, I think we're at the point that if you are hosting a web site on your server, and you cannot view the log files on your server, you have user permissioning issues. Fix those, then read your log files.

Comment: It is a shared host, who knows how they give you access to the logs :)

Answer (score 1):

Hey Session timeout its not execuate if some one is using site..

so no need to worry

(The Timeout property specifies the time-out period assigned to the Session object for the application, in minutes. If the user does not refresh or request a page within the time-out period, the session ends.

)
Session WIth IIS
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525473(v=vs.90).aspx

Session with Config File 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx

Comment: I want to change Session Timeout in web.config file of a particular asp.net application. Then link you provided tells about Session Timeout in IIS.

Comment: When I change the web.config all sessions expires

Comment: Hey dear... if you change anything(not only session) with web.config.... session always expire...  Thats is rules of Microsoft .. so not possible to achive that...

Comment: try with session mode = sql server   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6bb9cz9(v=vs.71).aspx ......

Answer (score 1):

I think the simple answer here is <strike>"not</strike> possible".. You live you learn, see answer on **ASP.NET Performance counters**. I'm very interested on how that goes (if it works for you), and if it gives you application specific data (vs. [aggregate of all applications on the box](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc775901%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?).

Even the suggestion to look at log files will not get you what you want - as you're looking at the log file, how would you know there isn't a user starting a session?

Sessions are cookies to a browser. So if visit 1 page in your web site, I leave your website and go to some other web site, and then come back (before whatever timeout value you set)? How would you define that? At the point I left your web site, you will not see "any" activity (whatever monitor you use), but that doesn't mean my session is "expired".

It doesn't even have to be that complicated - I visit your web site, and start reading your content (not navigating, not doing anything that can be measure/monitored).

I guess there's more clarity needed on the "goal" - as in what are you after? The objective of resetting isn't the real "goal" of what you want to achieve.

**Update:**

I know you said you can't modify the source code, so you can *hope* that it implements Google Analytics. If so, you can look at the **real time** activity of your web site. This at least gets you "somewhere" in some trivial fashion. **BUT** just the same, the "magic" is based on **cookies** (which therefore means its still subject to the questions I posed above)

Answer (score -1):

Keep increesing and decreesing an application variable at session start and session end events. then you will have the session count. if sesson count is zero, then you can reset the thing. all the best.