# How to know the active session counts for a particular website hosted in IIS using PowerShell

Tags: asp.net, iis, powershell, windows-server-2008, powershell-2.0

I asked a question about knowing the running session count in IIS.

[Get running session count from IIS for my hosted Asp.Net web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734561/get-running-session-count-from-iis-for-my-hosted-asp-net-web-site)

and I got the following powershell script

```
Write-host Getting performance counters ...

$perfCounterString = "\asp.net applications(__total__)\sessions active" 
$counter = get-counter -counter $perfCounterString 
$rawValue = $counter.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue 

write-host Session Count is $rawValue
```

Rightnow this script is giving active session count for all websites hosted in IIS

I just wanted to know how to modify this script so that it should give active session count only for a particular website.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$ServerName = 'IIs1'
$SiteName = 'default web site'

get-counter "\\$ServerName\web service($SiteName)\current connections"
```

Comment: hi, can i get a session by session id with this get-counter ?