# How to ping an application pool

Tags: powershell, iis-7, application-pool

We are trying to troubleshoot app pool hang scenarios, so one of the queue we thought of monitoring was http.sys queue.We need to check different parameters like app pool status and requests in queue.

Http.sys request queues are obtained from perfmon .Is there any way I can ping application pool and check status during each stage/requestload.

We are dealing this issue in two phases
1.Remove node out of HLB(we have script) once node is not responding or hung or slow, before end users complain( we get a lot of comlpaints)—priority 1
2.troubleshoot what’s the cause of hung—priority 2

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
This article looks promising.But not able to find how to execute this.Any help on this please.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691445(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure an app pool's state will tell you if it is hung, just if it is started, stopped, or changing states.

I think you'll want to look at the IIS performance counters. I've never had to do anything like that, but the [Get-Counter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx) cmdlet is probably what you'll use.

[Looks like there is another Stack Overflow question/answer that has some sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9920281/how-to-know-the-active-session-counts-for-a-particular-website-hosted-in-iis-usi):

```
Get-Counter "\\$ServerName\web service($SiteName)\current connections"):
```

Comment: Thank you .This is helpfull.let me change my way of troubleshooting