# How to check whether a website deployed in IIS 7.5 is being access by user or not?

Tags: asp.net

We have deployed 5 websites (read only data) in IIS 7.5 on last month now we want to remove those website which are not accessed/used by users. We have a total of 10 websites on IIS 7.5.

We don't want to make any setting changes on deployed site, those are deployed on last year and we want to remove them is no one access in last 4 months. We have onlu logfolder in Inetpub so is there any reliable way to get it done.

Comment: What is IIS 6.1? There 6.0, 7.0, and 7.5.

Comment: it was a typo, have updated question.

Answer (score 1):

on the web server turn on logging, and see how much traffic you get

Comment: Is there any link which i can follow for the details ?

Comment: We dont want to make any setting changes on deployed site, those are deployed on last year and we want to remove them is no one access in last 4 months. We have onlu logfolder in Inetpub so is there any reliable way to get it done.

Comment: if you are already logging, check check the logs to see how much it's being used

Answer (score 0):

Run PowerShell Script

```
write-host Getting performance counters ...

$perfCounterString = "\asp.net applications(__total__)\sessions active" 
$counter = get-counter -counter $perfCounterString 
$rawValue = $counter.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue 

write-host Session Count is $rawValue
```

See the following link for more details: 
[Get running session count from IIS for my hosted Asp.Net web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734561/get-running-session-count-from-iis-for-my-hosted-asp-net-web-site)

Comment: Will the above only work if the page / site has session state switched on ?